LattePanda Sigma 32GB + Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS + eGPU + NVIDIA + Thunderbolt 3 = problem
Last time I tried to connect the hardware like in the title, but I couldn't install it successfully. I use:

LattePanda Sigma 32GB with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and X11 (not Wayland)
eGPU eGFX Breakaway Box 550
NVIDIA Asus RTX 3060 V2 DUAL OC 12 GB
connection between LattePanda Sigma and eGPU via Thunderbolt 4 cable (eGPU is using Thunderbolt 3)

Has somebody tried to connect eGPU via Thunderbolt to Lattepanda Sigma on the Ubuntu system?
I tried to do this but I have a problem with drivers.
I installed Windows 10 on LattePanda Sigma and eGPU has been detected. I was able to switch on hardware acceleration for the web browser. 8K video on a 4K display connected to LattePanda Sigma via HDMI works very well. The display connected directly to the eGPU works also.
So now there can be a problem on Ubuntu with the NVIDIA driver because in general NVIDIA is recognized. Or maybe there is a conflict between the integrated GPU and NVidia card on the Ubuntu system. I checked that the Lenovo Thunderbolt 4 Dock works with LattePanda on Ubuntu (so Thunderbolt works with Ubuntu).
Sometimes, it's strange because I have to switch off/on the eGPU a few times. After all, the lights on NVIDIA are on. After all, the system does not recognize it.
And after I have to reboot Ubuntu.
In general, Ubuntu recognizes NVIDIA but I can't Install the driver properly.
I found a few tutorials on the Web and I made everything step-by-step to install the NVIDIA driver.
https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2021/debian-ubuntu-linux-mint-nvidia-guide/
https://medium.com/@wumeng9028/how-to-uninstall-nvidia-driver-and-install-the-latest-driver-in-ubuntu-96c0b2dc4cc4
https://tleyen.github.io/blog/2014/10/25/cuda-6-dot-5-on-aws-gpu-instance-running-ubuntu-14-dot-04/
Every time I faced with strange issue

ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'. This happens most
frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or
improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that
differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if another
driver, such as nouveau, is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel
module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA GPU(s), or no NVIDIA GPU
installed in this system is supported by this NVIDIA Linux graphics
driver release.


Please see the log entries 'Kernel module load error' and 'Kernel
messages' at the end of the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for
more information.

Has somebody faced with the same issue? I am very thankful for every tip, and advice. I don't have any idea how to solve this issue and connect this hardware.
Best regards

SOLUTION! :)
Finally, I installed the Nvidia driver after updating the kernel version. Now it works! You can use the commands below:

wget
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
chmod +x ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
sudo ./ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i v6.8.4
sudo reboot now

Now I must launch hardware acceleration using XRDP (Windows --> Ubuntu). Has somebody tried to do this?
